# node JS and Out of Range Error

Tags: node.js, telegram

I'm trying to build my first node js application, to manage some telegram account. I don't want to create a telegram bot, which is making it really hard since most example relating to node js and telegram is bot related. I seem to be running into a lot of roadblocks, this being one of them...

I am trying initialize a connection to telegram, but I am getting the following error

```
internal/buffer.js:35
throw new ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE('value', `>= ${min} and <= ${max}`, value);^
RangeError [ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE]: The value of "value" is out of range. It must      
>= 0 and <= 4294967295. Received -2083955988
```

and it seems to be happening on this line of code

```
const { MTProto } = require('telegram-mtproto')
```

this is what the init.js file looks like

```
console.log('start init')
const { MTProto } = require('telegram-mtproto')

console.log('const MTProto set')
const api = {
invokeWithLayer: 0xda9b0d0d,
layer: 57,
initConnection: 0x69796de9,
api_id: 12345,
app_version: '1.0.1',
lang_code: 'en'
}

console.log('init api set')
const server = { webogram: true, dev: true }

const telegram = MTProto({ api, server })

console.log('init complete')

module.exports = telegram
```

I have put in a number of console.logs to try and trace out exactly where the error occurs, the first log of 'start init' prints and then the error happens, If I remove or comment out the

```
const{MTProto}=require('telegram-mtproto')
```

line then it will print the second log of 'cont MTProto set'. I am not sure why I am getting this error or exactly what it means or how to fix / avoid it.

I am using visual Studio 2017 and have added the the telegram-mtproto package in the package.json file like this.

```
{
  "name": "test-telegram-login",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "testTelegramLogin",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
  "crypto-address": "0.0.2",
  "telegram-api": "^4.1.0",
  "telegram-mt-node": "^0.9.7",
  "telegram-mtproto": "^1.0.5"

 },
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need to update your WebSocket version or downgrade your Node.js version

I advice update the websocket module, in [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) file.

For example:

Change

```
"websocket": "^1.0.24"
```

to

```
"websocket": "^1.0.28"
```

Btw don't forget that you will need to delete your node_modules folder and do

```
npm install
```

for downloading all modules once again.
Of course if you don't want to download all modules, you can delete only ../node_modules/websocket folder and install websocket module.

```
npm install websocket
```